Как в режиме реального времени проверять вводимый пользователем текст в консоли на правильность?
Как в режиме реального времени проверять вводимый пользователем текст в консоли на правильность? Необходимо, чтобы программа на C++ проверяла каждую введённую пользователем букву. В случае ошибки, неправильная буква должна окрашиваться в красный цвет сразу после её ввода. Проверка должна осуществляться моментально по мере ввода символов.

Если Windows, работайте с консолью напрямую. Если Linux, ncurses.

getchar() пологаю или аналоги — это для отлова, ну и для окраски что-то из console.h и т.п.
